# The role of gradle

Tags: gradle

This might be a stupid question. Currently in my company the usage of gradle is starting to emerge. I have been learning about the basic of gradle and use it for my small projects.

Because of gradle's flexibility, the usage can be very vast. I'm coming from maven and now I'm confused about the role of gradle in our project as it is a *general-purpose* tool.

Here are some of the usages that pops questions in my head:

- Gradle tasks are treated as CLI sub commands. The command line arguments are passed as properties. It seems to me that the project can just be written as a normal java/groovy that uses library common-cli or args4j that are already quite mature (supporting help, usage, etc).
- Some of the sub projects are checked out using gradle instead of using the svn:externals.

My question is not about **how?**, it's more about **should it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle gives you a lot of flexibility, indeed. As it uses Groovy - you can really create all kind of workflows and commands. I'm not sure if this is the best practice though.

The best is when you can leverage the declarative side of Gradle (via Java plugin), the same way as you do with Maven - build by conventions, and then you may have customizations if you need to do something extra with the build artifacts. So Gradle is a kind of a tool that merges all the benefits from Maven and Ant, replacing XML with Groovy DSL.

What you described sounds more like a project with a very custom structure and the only thing you actually leveraged is the task execution engine. Same you would do with Ant. But you didn't mention, for instance, if you're using plugins.

> Some of the sub projects are checked out using gradle instead of using
>   the svn:externals

I think you could do the same with any other build tool out there. To me it sounds quite strange - there's already a CLI tool for that (svn, git, hg, ). Probably the person who established this had a desperate wish to accommodate all the commands into one tool, which is some cases may be quite useful, why not. But as you didn't provide more context, this all sounds like an overuse of scripting and over-engineering.

Comment: Upped for emphasizing the build by convention and only using the task execution engine.

Answer (score 0):

The features that are in gradle page shows a lot about this tool.
Gradle has the flexibility of ant and the conventions of Maven.  Gradle can use ANT and Maven.  Everything in Groovy.

```
Features
    Declarative builds and build-by-convention
        Gradle uses DSL(Domain Specific Language) based on Groovy.
    Language for dependency based programming
        The tasks are based in a hierarchy, favoring the builds
    Structure your build
        Easy to compose buid from reusable pieces
    Deep API
        Allow to monitor and customize the configuration and behavior execution
    Scalability
        Reusability allows one project uses parts of other projects increasing the produtivity
    Multi-project builds
        You can rebuild a project or its sub-project, that depends on another sub-project.
    Different ways to manage dependencies
        Maven has just one way.  Can integrate with maven and ivy, or just use jars or directories.
    Groovy
        Insteady of XML.
```